# if the date difference between two dates is X do this if is Y do something else

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My start date is 2009-04-01 (4th of april 2009), end date is getdate().

I need to calculate for every date from the start date until today some things. 
I also need to break it into two cases:

case 1: if it's a friday i need to go back 347 days , example

```
select datediff(dw, '2010-11-22','2011-11-04')
```

for every friday, then perform some selects.

case 2: if it's from monday to thursday then go back 349 days, example

```
   select datediff(dw, '2010-11-19','2011-11-03')
```

How can I write this, what I need to perform is not relevant just put it as:

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date
declare @dateHolder date
declare @tsID int
set @startDate = '2009-04-01'
set @endDate = getdate()
set datefirst 1;


while (select count (tsID) from #tempI)>0
            begin
            select top 1 @tsID = tsID from #tempI
                while (select count (rateDate) from #tempI)>0
                begin
                    select top 1 @dateHolder = rateDate from #tempI
                      case (select datename  (dw, @dateHolder) = '5' then  someColumn = @dateHolder - 347 as dateIneedToUseForMyFormula
                      case (select datename (dw, @dateHolder) = '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' then someColumn = @dateHolder - 349 as dateIneedToUseForMyFormula
-- here i don't know how to write the code, so i'll write pseudo
-- i have tsID rateDate and rate
-- i need to put in a new column (the value obtained from taking the value
-- from the column rate corresponding to the  @dateHolder - the value from
-- the column rate corresponding to the @dateHolder - 347 or 349 
-- depending on the case) * 100

                end
            delete from #tempI where @dateHolder = rateDate
        end
    delete from #tempI where @tsID = tsID
    end
```

**EDIT**
I was asked in the comments what to do, and given the downvotes, I don't think i made myself clear. I will copy paste what i wrote in the comment:
"
first to iterate through all the tsID in the list, after doing that to iterate through all the dates, get a date subtract 349 or 347 days from it, then check put in a new column the result of : the value of the 'rate' column which corresponds to my date - the value of the 'rate' column which corresponds to the date from 349 or 347 days ago. This performed for all the dates for every id "

**edit 2: Expected output**

```
 tsID rateDate     rate    calculated 
  1    2009-04-01  0.12     null 
  1    2009-04-02  0.14     null 
  1    2009-04-03  0.11     null 
  2    2009-04-01  0.01     null 
  2    2009-04-02  0.012    null
  2    2009-04-03  0.43     null 
. . . 347 days later or 349 depending
     on what 2009-04-01 was 
  1   2010-03-16   0.454   (0.454 - 0.12)*100
  1   2010-03-17   0.34    (0.34 - 0.14)*100 
  1   2010-03-18   0.9     (0.9 - 0.11)*100 
then same for id 2.3...4...
```

Comment: Please decide what version of sql server you are working with.

Comment: SQL sever 2012, the syntax shouldn't be too different than 2008 :)

Comment: Tip: You might want to consider using `DatePart` and comparing integers rather than fiddling about with `DateName` and strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Declare @start Date='2009-09-01', @end Date=getdate();
;With NumberSequence( Number ) as
(
    Select @start as Number
        union all
    Select DATEADD(d,1,Number)
        from NumberSequence
        where Number < @end
)
Select 
(CASE WHEN (datepart(dw,Number) =6)  THEN DATEADD(d,-347,Number)
     ELSE DATEADD(d,-349,Number)
     END ) AS Date
From NumberSequence Option (MaxRecursion 10000)
```

Comment: thank you, but how do i incorporate this into my iteration process? Also, why do you put 6 here? CASE WHEN (datepart(dw,Number) =6) , in my code i use datefirst = 1. Shouldn't be 5?

Comment: @viorelmunteanu m not getting exactly what u want??

Comment: first to iterate through all the tsID in the list, after doing that to iterate through all the dates, get a date subtract 349 or 347 days from it, then check put in a new column the result of : the value of the 'rate' column which corresponds to my date - the value of the 'rate' column which corresponds to the date from 349 or 347 days ago. This performed for all the dates for every id.

Comment: That  depends on what u put in datefirst,if it 1 then 6 should be replace by 5.

Comment: I just made an edit, please find it in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement with weekday:

```
Select Case 
    When WeekDAy(yourdate, 3) < 4 then datediff(dw, '2010-11-19','2011-11-03')
    when WeekDAy(yourdate, 3) = 4 then datediff(dw, '2010-11-22','2011-11-04')
    Else ...?... End
```